# How to allow users to change password before they logging in?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to allow the users to change their password before logging in. In practice I have LoginActivity that with a clickable textview redirects to an activity where the user enters his email and the new password to be set. The problem is that when the user tries to log in, it fails. Is it possible to do this or do I have to change the method?

This is my code:

```
private EditText emailRetrieve, firstPassword, passwordConfirm;
    private Button resetPasswordBtn;
    private String email, password, passwordToConfirm = "";

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_password);
        uploadUI();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        resetPasswordBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setNewPassword();
            }
        });
    }

    // Validation email and password
    private boolean validation() {

        boolean valid = true;

        email = emailRetrieve.getText().toString();
        password = firstPassword.getText().toString();
        passwordToConfirm = passwordConfirm.getText().toString();

        if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            emailRetrieve.setError("Insert valid email address");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            emailRetrieve.setError(null);
        }

        if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 8) {
            firstPassword.setError("Insert valid password");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            firstPassword.setError(null);
        }

        if(passwordToConfirm.isEmpty() || (!passwordToConfirm.equals(password))) {
            passwordConfirm.setError("Passwords must be equals");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            passwordConfirm.setError(null);
        }

        return valid;

    }
    
    
    private String getPasswordToConfirm(TextView textView) {

        String confirm = textView.getText().toString();
        return confirm;

    }

    private void setNewPassword() {

        if(!validation())
            return;

        Utils.loadProgressDialog(SetPasswordActivity.this, "Uploading...");

        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("users");
        myRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    for(DataSnapshot datasnap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        if(datasnap.child("email").getValue().toString().equals(email)) {
                            datasnap.child("password").getRef().setValue(getPasswordToConfirm(passwordConfirm))
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                                            Toast.makeText(SetPasswordActivity.this, "Password successfully changed",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                throw error.toException();
            }
        });

        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));

    }

    @Override
    public void uploadUI() {
        emailRetrieve = findViewById(R.id.email_retrieve);
        firstPassword = findViewById(R.id.first_password);
        passwordConfirm = findViewById(R.id.password_confirm);
        resetPasswordBtn = findViewById(R.id.reset_password_btn);
    }
```

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are navigating user to `LoginActivity` before the `password` is changed, `Firebasedatabase` call is asynchronous and you have to take user to `LoginActivity` only on Success, that is when you are showing toast to user. Basically move `startActivity` in `setNewpassword` to `onSuccess` of firebase query

```
 private void setNewPassword() {
            if(!validation())
                return;
            Utils.loadProgressDialog(SetPasswordActivity.this, "Uploading...");
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("users");
            myRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        for(DataSnapshot datasnap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            if(datasnap.child("email").getValue().toString().equals(email)) {
                                datasnap.child("password").getRef().setValue(getPasswordToConfirm(passwordConfirm))
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                                                  startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
                                   
                             Toast.makeText(SetPasswordActivity.this, "Password successfully changed",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    throw error.toException();
                }
            });
   }
```

Comment: The user is redirected from LoginActivity to another activity (SetPasswordActivity) and once the password is changed, the user is redirected back to the LoginActivity. Here the problem arises as firebase doesn't recognize the changed password and therefore does not allow the user to log in. I tried your solution but nothing changed